# Function fitting neural network in for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-structures, machine-learning, statistics, neural-network

I'm using MATLAB R2014a version.

I have ten clusters of **`X`**, and **`y`** data.

I want to fit these 10 corresponding data model by using a neural network tool in MATLAB. And I want to save 10 different models in somewhere.

For each cluster, I need to design an implementation to determine the correct number of hidden layers. And I will save each model into an array or something like that. And then continue for the 2nd cluster.

For this aim, I have developed this algorithm:

```
for q = 1:z                             % number of clusters
    mdl  = fitnet( 10 );
    mdl  = train( mdl, X( classes == q ), y( classes == q ) );

    view( mdl );

    yy   = net( X( classes == q ) );
    perf = perform( net, yy, y( classes == q ) );

    model( q ).mdl = mdl;
    clear mdl;
end
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
Error using view (line 67)
Invalid input arguments

Error in Main (line 97)
    view(mdl);
```

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: What are you triying to do with `view`? Because it does not do what you think it does. It sets a viewpoint in 3D plots. http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html

Comment: Do not use randomly Matlab function and expect they do what you want!

Comment: Would you mind to show the actual state of your pre-set data? A `whos` command output may help as a 1st step and some inspection of values / types beheld in these will help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike mentioned in the comments view() **is** the right function to choose here because it has been overloaded to also show a sketch of a neural network (see here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/view.html).

So, the problem obviously is not view() itself, but your mdl-network which means you should:

- go there with a debugger and check if it really is a neural network and if it contains values
- check those values because X and y might not be the vectors you want (which you should also check)

...and/or post more information about what's going on in your code.